# run-time check failure #2 || C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for school and cannot figure out why I keep getting this error message that is telling me the stack around a variable has been corrupted. I have looked at other posts about the message and already tried adding to the number of places in the 2D array.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "\n***QB Rating Calculator***\n";
    
    int games[sixteen] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 };
    float passes[sixteen][sixteen];
    
    float tds[sixteen];
    float Int[sixteen];
    float yards[sixteen];
    float rating[sixteen];
    int choice = 0;
    string name;
    ofstream print_file;
    print_file.open("QB_Rating.txt");
    //Collect data
    cout << "What is youre Quarter Backs name?\n";
    getline(cin, name);
    get_data(games, passes, tds, Int, yards, sixteen);

    //User choice NFL or NCAA
    system("pause");
    cout << "_______________________________________";
    cout << "\nIs your Quarterback in the NFL or NCAA?";
    cout << "\n1.NFL\n";
    cout << "\n2.NCAA\n";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:NFL(games, passes, tds, Int, yards, sixteen, rating);
        break;
    case 2:NCAA(games, passes, tds, Int, yards, sixteen, rating);
        break;
    }
    //Display output
    
    cout << "\n\n" << name << "\n";
    print_file << name;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
        cout << "*****************************************\n";
        cout << "Game " << games[i] << " Quarterback rating was: " << rating[i] << "\n";
        print_file << "*************************************\n";
        print_file << "Game:" << games[i] << "\nQB rating : " << rating[i] << "\n";
    }
    print_file.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Retrieves and validates data
void get_data(int games[], float passes[sixteen][sixteen], float tds[], float Int[], float yards[], int sixteen)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n*****************************************\n";
        cout << "\nCompletions in game " << games[i] << ": ";
        cin >> passes[sixteen][i];
        while (passes[sixteen][i] < 0) {
            cout << "\nCompletions cannot be negative. Try again.";
            cout << "\nCompletions in game " << games[i] << ": ";
            cin >> passes[sixteen][i];
        }
        cout << "\nPass attempts in game " << games[i] << ": ";
        cin >> passes[i][sixteen];
        while (passes[i][sixteen] < 0) {
            cout << "\nPass attempts cannot be negative!\n";
            cout << "\nPass attempts in game " << games[i] << ": ";
            cin >> passes[i][sixteen];
        }
        cout << "\nTouchdowns thrown in game " << games[i] << ": ";
        cin >> tds[i];
        while (tds[i] < 0) {
            cout << "\nYou cannot throw negative touchdowns!";
            cout << "\nTouchdowns thrown in game " << games[i] << ": ";
            cin >> tds[i];
        }
        cout << "\nInterceptions thrown in game " << games[i] << ": ";
        cin >> Int[i];
        while (Int[i] < 0) {
            cout << "\nYou cannot throw negative interceptions!";
            cout << "\nInterceptions thrown in game " << games[i] << ": ";
            cin >> Int[i];
        }
        cout << "\nYards thrown for in game " << games[i] << ": ";
        cin >> yards[i];
        while (yards[i] < 0) {
            cout << "\nYou cannot throw for negative yards. Try again";
            cout << "\nYards thrown for in game " << games[i] << ": ";
            cin >> yards[i];
        }

    }
}
//NFL
void NFL(int games[], float passes[sixteen][sixteen], float tds[], float Int[], float yards[], int sixteen, float rating[]) {
    float a, b, c, d;
    for (int i = 0; i < sixteen; i++) {
        a = (((passes[sixteen][i] / passes[i][sixteen]) * 100) - 30) / 20;
        b = ((tds[i] / passes[i][sixteen]) * 100) / 5;
        c = (9.5 - ((Int[i] / passes[i][sixteen]) * 100)) / 4;
        d = ((yards[i] / passes[i][sixteen]) - 3) / 4;
        rating[i] = (a + b + c + d) / .06;
        cout << " " << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d;
    }
}
//NCAA
void NCAA(int games[], float passes[sixteen][sixteen], float tds[], float Int[], float yards[], int sixteen, float rating[]) {
    float a, b, c, d;
    for (int i = 0; i < sixteen; i++) {
        a = (passes[sixteen][i] / passes[i][sixteen]) * 100;
        b = (tds[i] / passes[i][sixteen]) * 100;
        c = (Int[i] / passes[i][sixteen]) * 100;
        d = yards[i] / passes[i][sixteen];
        rating[i] = a + (3.3 * b) - (2 * c) + (8.4 * d);
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ofstream print_file; print_file.open("QB_Rating.txt");` to `ofstream print_file("QB_Rating.txt");`. And you don't need to call `print_file.close();`. The detractor will do that.

Comment: Another tip, in `get_data()` I'd recommend using `if() goto` instead of the while loops. That way you dont have to repeat yourself

Comment: Just tried that and it worked. thanks for the help!

Comment: @Fullaccess -- no, don't use `goto`. Just use a `do .. while()` loop.

Comment: Um, `passes[sixteen][i]` -- the first index is out of bounds. And why in the world would you have what seems to be a constant named `sixteen` whose value is 16? Sure, we like descriptive names, but that's a bit too literal. <g> What is its role?

Comment: I was told to setup a constant definition for the size of the array. What do you mean out of bounds?

Comment: If you declare `int myArray[16]` you can only read the values [0, 15] (well, you can read values beyond 15. But you'll invoke undefined behavior). The rule goes as follows: For an array of size n, you can read from 0 to n-1. If `sixteen` is a constant defined as `16`, you cant use it to read from the last row in the matrix, because the last row has index 15. In that case, the index is said to be "out of bounds".

Comment: that top valid entry in `Int` is 15, indexes go from 0 to size -1, same for all other arrays